# BigQuery says query is valid, but returns 'Field customerid not found'

Tags: google-bigquery

This is the query that I am running - as I said, BigQuery says it is valid but returns an error once I run the query. I've run this query in Postgres (making the necessary change for the different UNION ALL syntax) and it works as expected. Any help would be appreciated as I'm relatively new to BQ. Thanks.

#### Error Message

```
Query Failed
Error: Field 'customerid' not found.
```

#### Query

```
SELECT jobs.customerid,
       jobs.total,
       jobs.count,
       city_max.city
FROM
  (SELECT customerid,
          sum(total) AS total,
          count(*) AS count
   FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401] group by customerid ) AS jobs
JOIN 
  (SELECT customer_city_count.customerid,
          city,
          city_count
   FROM
     (SELECT customerid,
             city,
             count(*) AS city_count
      FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401]

      GROUP BY customerid, city) AS customer_city_count
    JOIN
     (SELECT customerid,
             max(ct) AS max_ct
      FROM
        (SELECT customerid,
                city,
                count(*) AS ct
         FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401] 
         GROUP BY customerid, city)
      GROUP BY customerid) AS customer_max_city ON customer_max_city.customerid = customer_city_count.customerid
   AND city_count = customer_max_city.max_ct) AS city_max ON city_max.customerid = jobs.customerid
```

Comment: show error message!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant updated with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery is quite sensitive to aliases/field naming.
Try below

```
SELECT jobs.customerid,
       jobs.total,
       jobs.count,
       city_max.city
FROM
  (SELECT customerid,
          SUM(total) AS total,
          COUNT(*) AS COUNT
   FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401] GROUP BY customerid ) AS jobs
JOIN 
  (SELECT customer_city_count.customerid as customerid,
          city,
          city_count
   FROM
     (SELECT customerid,
             city,
             COUNT(*) AS city_count
      FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401]

      GROUP BY customerid, city) AS customer_city_count
    JOIN
     (SELECT customerid,
             MAX(ct) AS max_ct
      FROM
        (SELECT customerid,
                city,
                COUNT(*) AS ct
         FROM [events.transaction_20160301],[events.transaction_20160401] 
         GROUP BY customerid, city)
      GROUP BY customerid) AS customer_max_city ON customer_max_city.customerid = customer_city_count.customerid
   AND city_count = customer_max_city.max_ct) AS city_max ON city_max.customerid = jobs.customerid
```

There is only one change here in below line

```
SELECT customer_city_count.customerid as customerid
```